# Bash-Script is not executing command, but if command entered manually, it works

Tags: bash, shell-script, bashrc, bash-expansion, bashdb

this is my bash-script:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 3
sudo apt-get update && echo 'y' | sudo apt-get upgrade
cd /opt/
sleep 5
wget http://dl.4players.de/ts/releases/3.0.13.6/teamspeak3-server_linux_amd64-3.0.13.6.tar.bz2
sleep 10
tar -jxvf teamspeak3-server_linux_amd64-3.0.13.6.tar.bz2
sleep 10
mv /opt/teamspeak3-server_linux_amd64 /opt/teamspeak
cd /opt/teamspeak
sudo echo 'cd /opt/teamspeak && chown -R root:root *'
sudo echo 'cd /opt/teamspeak && ./ts3server_startscript.sh start'
sudo echo 'cd /opt/teamspeak && ./ts3server_startscript.sh stop'
sudo echo 'cd /opt/teamspeak && ./ts3server_startscript.sh start serveradmin_password=XXX'
```

It suddenly looks like the last 4 commands do not work. Do you have any idea why? It isnt the content, as it works when i enter it manually.

Answer (score 1):

I gather what you want is not to `echo` the commands, but to execute them. Try this:

```
cd /opt/teamspeak && sudo chown -R root:root *
cd /opt/teamspeak && sudo ./ts3server_startscript.sh start
cd /opt/teamspeak && sudo ./ts3server_startscript.sh stop
cd /opt/teamspeak && sudo ./ts3server_startscript.sh start serveradmin_password=XXX
```

Comment: Additionally, you can avoid using `cd /opt/teamspeak` 4 times and executing it only once at the beginning of the last 4 commands.

Comment: @ZumodeVidrio :-)